# Can I maintain the state of a docker container without commiting

Tags: docker

I have a docker container running and would like to know if I can save its state without commiting it. 
For example:
1. Start container
2. Create a new file inside it
3. Exit container
4. Start container

Can the file still exist in this container without running docker commit before exiting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker's `stopped`, `exited` Containers, Maintain files and changes in container's writable `AUFS layer`. Please note **this layer will be removed when the container is removed**.

POC:

```
sudo docker run -it --name test debian:jessie /bin/bash
root@3d01feb251bd:/# touch farhad
root@3d01feb251bd:/# exit

sudo docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
3d01feb251bd        debian:jessie       "/bin/bash"              16 seconds ago      Exited (0) 7 seconds ago                       test

sudo docker start test

sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
3d01feb251bd        debian:jessie       "/bin/bash"         31 seconds ago      Up 8 seconds                            test

sudo docker exec -it test /bin/bash
root@3d01feb251bd:/# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  farhad  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

As you can see the file I touched before exiting the container is still there.

Comment: Actuall my fault perhaps was that I wasn't seeing the state to maintain if I execute this:
1. docker run ....
2. exit
3. docker run...

but as I understand then I have different containers

Comment: @KostasKarkaletsis `Docker run` will create a new container with new writable layer, `Docker start` will start an existing container, and maintains the writable layer.

Comment: Clearest explanation about docker image and container! Thanks!!